# Navigating forms and grabbing DOM-Elements from a website using Guzzle/Goutte (PHP, Debugging)

Tags: php, guzzle, goutte

I'm fairly new to PHP and playing around with Goutte/Guzzle to grab some basic information from a website after filling out a few forms.

However I have problems finding issues (there might be a ton of them) since I could not find a way to display or console log any of the results or problems. The script finishes with Code 0 but does not return anything. A tip on how to print out what is currently stored in $client would already go a long way.

Here is the whole code I'm trying to run with a bunch of comments for clarification. I'm sorry for using such a large block, but any of this could have issues.

```php
<?php

use Goutte\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Client as GuzzleClient;

class grabPlate
{
    // WKZ
    public function checkPlate
    {
        $goutteClient = new Client();
        $guzzleClient = new GuzzleClient(array(
            'cookies'  => true,
            'timeout' => 60,
        ));
        $goutteClient->setClient($guzzleClient);

        $crawler = $goutteClient->request('GET', 'https://kfz-portal.berlin.de/kfzonline.public/start.html?oe=00.00.11.000000');

        //Click the first "Start" in the top left
        $link = $crawler
            ->filter('a:contains("Start")')
            ->eq(0)
            ->link()
        ;
        $crawler = $client->click($link);


        //Check checkbox, fill in name and press the button
        $buttonCrawlerNode = $crawler->selectButton('Weiter');
        $form = $buttonCrawlerNode->form();
        $form['gwt-uid-1']->tick();
        $form['select2-hidden-accessible']->select('Herr');
        $form['gwt-uid-4'] = 'John';
        $form['gwt-uid-5'] = 'Doe';
        $client->submit($form);

        //Fill some Data into the forms and search
        $buttonCrawlerNode = $crawler->selectButton('Button-3616');
        $form = $buttonCrawlerNode->form();
        $form['.kfzonline-KennzeichenGrossEb'] = 'AB';
        $form['.kfzonline-KennzeichenGrossEn'] = '123';
        $client->submit($form);

        //Extract collection
        $info = $crawler->extract('.collection');

        //return 1 if something is inside collection, 0 if it's empty
        if($info == NULL) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }




    }
}
 ?>
```

As I said just running the script in PHPStorm returns the status 0. However when plugging it into an API and accessing it, I get a server timeout response.

Answer (score 0):

You should either use a Debugging. Install xDebug to do so in PHP. This is also easy to integrate into Phpstorm.
Alternatively use `var_dump()` for printing out debug information about variables of any type to console.

Comment: I will try both of these options. Thank you for the fast response!

Answer (score 0):

You can display the requested page inside your php page, you have to add this snippet :

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$res = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.facebook.com/');
echo $res->getBody();
```